# How do I disable webrtc and javascript in Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webrtc, fingerprint

I want to disable webrtc and javascript in Chrome I've read a few posts and the consensus is this can't be done in python with chromedriver.  Though there is little on this topic.    Is there a way around this or is this still just not possible?

I'm needing these features because it is leaking proxy location.  You could I suppose do this manually through the profiles yourself and load it.  But depending on your number of profiles.. get ready for a lot of time to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the chrome capabilities, and open the driver with the configuration you need. [On this page](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), there are many useful properties like "--disable-rtc-smoothness-algorithm". This is an example with Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: This really does not look like Python haha XD.  I could probably make python equivalents but even then will it work? Hmm

Comment: It is only an example with how to use the capabilities and the chrome options. In the link you have many options about rtc and Javascript. I don't know well which one you need.

Comment: Uh I see.  I cannot find anywhere to actually disable javascript so to speak on that page.  Lots of java script related stuff, I will give it a try nonetheless.

Comment: I edited with Python example and disable javascript option.

Comment: This does not disable javascript for me on whoer.net

Comment: I think you can disable it somehow though.  Webrtc would be disabled by this method too assuming it works